# how to utilize sakai lesson builder for version 2.8

Tags: tomcat5.5, maven-tomcat-plugin, sakai

I have installed Sakai on a dedicated server, and was looking into some features as deploying lesson builder. Does anyone know as of how to deploy this tool? Or any other tool like Calendar. I a newbie in sakai environment, so not sure how to proceed with such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lessons is now included by default in Sakai 2.9.

Alternatively, you need to run the compatible tag for it to work in 2.8, check the install guide in the source for Lessons.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you post your questions to the Sakai-user forum @collab.sakaiproject.com, the SO forums do not seem to have much of any Sakai usage or supporters.

Comment: I moved on to another LMS, as sakai seamed way too overwhelmed for the focus I was going to use for.